# Angular Material -- having a hard time finding what modules to load in standalone components from the documentation

Tags: angular, angular-material

Working with Angular 16 with the fully stand-alone component project structure. When I want to add a new Angular Material component, I'm having a hard time nailing down which Module I need to add to my imports array. I'm using https://material.angular.io/components/categories to learn how to use the components but they don't spell out which Module to load for each component. Am I missing something?

For example in order to add the `<mat-slide-toggle>` component, I need to add `import {MatSlideToggleModule} from "@angular/material/slide-toggle"` at the top and `imports: [MatSlideToggleModule]` to the component definition. This info, however, is missing from the docs: [image: docs example]

Comment: Might they just rely on the naming convention? It's probably not a coincidence that the component selector, the import path, and the module have the same name when accounting for the different capitalization styles ...

Comment: Maybe, but `MatExpansionModule` is imported in order to  use the `<mat-accordion>` component, so, the convention doesn't work everywhere.

Comment: If you look at the API tab for given component, the first line is the information about module import.